# Use file to know how big to make array Java

Tags: java, arrays, fileinputstream

I am inputting a file into my program that has over 4000 lines in it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String[] nameArray;

    readNamesFile(nameArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4429; i++){
        System.out.println(nameArray[i]);
    }

}

private static void readNamesFile(String[] nameArray) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    String fileName = "names.txt";
    inputStream = new Scanner (new File(fileName));

    int i = 0;

    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        nameArray[i] = inputStream.nextLine();

        i++;
    }

    inputStream.close();
}

}
```

now the way that it is isn't working because my nameArray hasn't been initialized yet. Is there a way I can use the length of the text file I am inputting in to have my array that size? Or is it just best to find out the maximum total of inputs I will have ([this](http://www.writeurl.com/text/2uu287wyl7rw9bls7y4q/mq34g5evmtu1f2y9x2yn) <-- is my file by the way). 4429 is the amount of inputs in the file.. Just don't think I am able to use that number I did ask my professor though

Comment: Is the use of Array is essential u can also use Collection (ArrayList) for that ?

Comment: When parsing a file I generally store lines or objects derived from lines in a `LinkedList`, which can be converted to an `ArrayList` later with a single allocation. Might not be the most efficient, but it works well when you have no idea how much space you need ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`LineNumberReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html).

```
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("names.txt"))); // Your file name
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
int size = lnr.getLineNumber() + 1; // +1 because line numbering begins at 0
lnr.close();

// Use the size for your array declarationg
String[] nameArray = new String[size];
```

*Note:* To know the size, the file has to be read twice(if the you insist on using an array), either by manually looping through it or letting built-in classes do that. Otherwise, the you can use an `ArrayList` instead of an array, since an `ArrayList` is dynamic and thus, you don't have to worry about fixing a size.

Comment: This implies reading the file twice. `lnr` needs to be closed.

Comment: To know that, the file has to be read twice(if the OP insists on using an array), either manually by looping through it or letting in-built classes do that. Otherwise, the OP can use an `ArrayList` instead of an array. And I actually think I'm gonna put this in the answer as well.

Comment: Well that would have definitely worked for me but our professor said in the constraints that he only wants to file to be read once in the entire program

Comment: @user3044041 - And that constraint was never in this question. Why so? Anyways, with that constraint, you need to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Got it! sorry I should have included that constraint haha, but I thank you for the help

Comment: @user3044041 - No problem. Hope you got a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is not correct. You should return `String[]`. Try,

```
 static String[] readNamesFile() {
    String[] nameArray= new  String[4429];
    //put the file String here
    ...........

   return  nameArray;
 }
```

At `main` method, get the return array and print

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

  String[] nameArray= readNamesFile();

 for (int i = 0; i < 4429; i++){
    System.out.println(nameArray[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? And also, why does the OP have to do this?